# How to use my phone as a WiFi adapter for playing lan games

Tags: wi-fi, lan

I just want to play lan games and use wireless apps because my pc doesnt have WiFi so I want to use my damaged display phone as WiFi for lan games in pc
And also use pc remote from my other phone
-WiFi adapter
-lan games (pc)
-phone
-pc have no WiFi
Hope you understand
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Using a phone as Wifi adapter for gaming is IMHO a bad idea. First it is very complex and error prone and second it adds extra latency because the data as to be first transferred via USB (multiple conversions) to the device which sends the data then via Wifi to the router. Buying a cheap Wifi adapter with external antenna and using an USB extension cable is the more simple way.

Comment: https://www.amazon.in/Cost2Cost1-Wireless-N-Receiver-Adapter-300Mbps/dp/B07F6FFR39?tag=googinhydr18418-21 will this work to play lan games and apps

Comment: I would not use such a micro Wifi dongle - the antenna is very little and can not be positioned. I prefer adapters like TP-Link N150.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert said it's not the best idea but if you still want to do it first turn off mobile data and connect to WIFI then connect your phone to the pc then on your phone go to network and internet then tap hotspot & tethering and enable USB tethering.

Comment: Tried every thing stil not recognizing after entering the ip